Can a signatory country to the International Criminal Court withdraw to evade obligation to comply with an issued order?
The International Criminal Court (ICC) issued arrest warrants for Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and former defense minister Yoav Gallant:

THE HAGUE, Nov 21 (Reuters) - The International Criminal Court issued arrest warrants on Thursday for Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and his former defence chief, as well as a Hamas leader, Ibrahim Al-Masri, for alleged war crimes and crimes against humanity in the Gaza conflict.

Disclosed reasons:

In their decision, the ICC judges said there were reasonable grounds to believe Netanyahu and Yoav Gallant were criminally responsible for acts including murder, persecution and starvation as a weapon of war as part of a "widespread and systematic attack against the civilian population of Gaza".

The ICC lacks police force or enforcement body to carry out the arrests and relies entirely on the cooperation of its 124 member states commitment to comply with the court orders.
While reactions globally remain polarized, the ICC host state, the Netherlands, publicly declared its endorsement of and willingness to carry out the court's order:

The Netherlands' foreign minister Caspar Veldkamp said his country was prepared to act upon the warrants.

The question is, can signatory countries who are strong allies of Israel such as Germany and Austria pull some kind of stunt to evade their obligation by withdrawing from the ICC?

FYI, the current German chancellor isn't likely to do this https://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-slams-germany-for-saying-itd-comply-with-icc-warrants-against-israeli-leaders/ I'm not sure if you were unaware of that and you are asking this as a theoretical question.

"...evade their obligation..." It might not be necessary as long as the subject of the order does not travel into the areas of the signatory countries unwilling to fulfill this obligation. Therefore it wouldn't really be needed at the moment.

This question is similar to: Did any ICC member state country ever refuse to arrest members indicted by the ICC?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There isn’t a need to do anything other then not take any action to arrest the person in question and that has happened in the past as indicated in the duplicate.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution that's true, but in this instance Netanhayu is supposed to travel to Hungary in a short while. Hungary's obligations, and those of the european countries the plane will certainly fly over, will probably come into question at that time.

@JoeW I don't see how that's similar at all. That one is a historical question (has X ever happened?). This is a "what is possible?" question (can Y happen?). Note that X and Y are not even the same thing here: the other question is about non-compliance, while this one is about avoiding a compliance requirement altogether by withdrawing from the ICC's jurisdiction. Just because two questions are vaguely related doesn't make them duplicates.

@JBentley the purpose of this question appears to be what can a signatory country do in order to not act on an arrest warrant and the linked question shows that countries have just ignored it in the past.

A country doesn't need to withdraw from the ICC if it doesn't want to execute an ICC arrest warrant against a foreign dignitary in its country. My answer to this question - Is an ICC warrant sufficient to override diplomatic immunity in signatory nations? - highlights this.
The Rome Statute that governs the ICC allows any country to withdraw from it. Russia is a recent example of a country that withdrew from the ICC when they started investigating Russia.
Most African countries are members of the ICC. An article in Al-Jazeera - Unplanned obsolescence: The ICC and the African Union (2013) - highlights that the countries comprising the African Union have once even considered mass withdrawal from the ICC.
European Union countries can face political issues in withdrawing from the ICC as their membership to the EU is contingent upon them being a part of the ICC:

All Member States have ratified the Rome Statute. ...
The principles of the Rome Statute, as well as those governing the functioning of the International Criminal Court (hereinafter the ‘ICC’), are fully in line with the principles and objectives of the Union ... The Union is convinced that universal accession to the Rome Statute is essential for the full effectiveness of the ICC ... Council Decision 2011/168/CFSP

In Benjamin Netanyahu arrest warrant: Where can he still go in Europe? (2024), Politico recently reported that the Netherlands, Ireland, Belgium, Spain, Austria, Slovenia have publicly stated full support to the ICC and that they will arrest Netanyahu (and Gallant) if it is within their jurisdiction to do so. Hungary has stated it will not arrest him, and even plans to invite Netanyahu to Hungary. Germany, Czechia, Italy, France, The United Kingdom have non-committally stated that they support the ICC but will examine the legal and political issues as it evolves, and when necessary.
The BBC however suggests that the current labour government in UK will be inclined to arrest Netanyahu if he comes to the UK. According to it, the new Labour government has scrapped its predecessor's plan to challenge the right of the ICC to issue arrest warrants. Emily Thornberry, Labour chair of the foreign affairs (UK) was quoted by Sky News saying:

"If Netanyahu comes to Britain, our obligation under the Rome Convention would be to arrest him under the warrant from the ICC. Not really a question of should, we are required to because we are members of the ICC."

RT reports that Netherlands, Switzerland, Ireland, Italy, Sweden, Belgium, Austria and Norway "all claimed they would meet their commitments and obligations under the Rome Statute and international law".
RBC-Ukraine and RT report that Italy is campaigning in the G7 Foreign Ministers meet to "suspend" ICC proceedings against the Israeli leaders until the Gaza conflict is "resolved":

... the Italian foreign minister noted that while the court makes “legal decisions,” Western governments are responsible for “political choices.” “We need to be united on this,” Tajani reportedly said during the G7 meeting.


Your "European Union countries ... membership to the EU is contingent upon them being a part of the ICC" seems a stretch.  Council Decision 2011/168/CFSP says that they had all joined and that the rest of the world joining would be a good thing, but not that they had to stay joined.

@Henry It is a condition to becoming a part of the EU, so quitting it would not be taken lightly by the EU.

They certainly could (EU obligations aside).  They most likely wouldn't.

It would be externally quite embarrassing to be seen to impede the court's work and may also cause internal backlash by their electorate.

A country presumably joined the ICC for a number of reasons, and Israel aside, those motivations still apply and would be frustrated by this move.


From following international news over the years, in cases where visits are "politically sensitive", this is conventionally resolved in a much less disruptive manner, where the embarrassing ally is just asked to kindly stay away from the national territory.  Or to send a different representative.  That request is itself is rarely made public as well, but can be inferred by press coverage and the absence of the embarrassing person from events which they could reasonably be expected to attend, followed by feverish press speculation.
Full text of Rome Statute

Article 127 Withdrawal



A State Party may, by written notification addressed to the Secretary-General of the
United Nations, withdraw from this Statute. The withdrawal shall take effect one year
after the date of receipt of the notification, unless the notification specifies a later date.




A State shall not be discharged, by reason of its withdrawal, from the obligations
arising from this Statute while it was a Party to the Statute, including any financial
obligations which may have accrued. Its withdrawal shall not affect any cooperation
with the Court in connection with criminal investigations and proceedings in relation
to which the withdrawing State had a duty to cooperate and which were commenced
prior to the date on which the withdrawal became effective, nor shall it prejudice in any
way the continued consideration of any matter which was already under consideration
by the Court prior to the date on which the withdrawal became effective.


p.s. Other countries, outside Europe, have at times just ignored the ICC requests. You'll find Sudan's al-Bashir in that club.

Few countries, including the seven he visited that are signatories to the ICC, harbor the political will to arrest him, despite the ICC urging all states to cooperate fully with the warrant for his arrest. On Saturday, Bashir travelled to Indonesia to head the opening session for an extraordinary Islamic summit, a country the Sudanese president was unable to visit last year due to pressure from several protesting countries. In February Bashir attended the African Investment Forum (AIF) in Egypt, where Sudan, Egypt, and Ethiopia agreed to strengthen ties. It is his sixth trip to the country, a signatory of the ICC that refuses to execute the warrant, since 2009.

p.p.s Hungary's intent to host Netanyahu are part and parcel of Orban's squabbling with the EU.  Remember that at times, with his support for Putin and his other autocratic tendencies, the EU has mulled on how to "punish" Orban.  It does not represent the position of most European countries.  At most you might expect Italy or the like to follow suit, due to Meloni's right wing government seeing some political benefit to doing so, but even that is unlikely - she's been way more restrained in her administration since her election than people had been wont of worrying about beforehand.

A State shall not be discharged, by reason of its withdrawal, from the obligations arising from this Statute while it was a Party to the Statute No legal expert but I wonder "how arising while it was a party" would play out if pushed.  Is that just with regards to enforcement?  Or to membership when the - alleged - offenses were committed?

Hungary has declared their intent to do so.

Note that the EU issue can be solved by just withdrawing from that as well.

@JBentley Because Brexit worked out so very well.

@ItalianPhilosopher I wasn't trying to imply that it did (or not). We're talking about extreme scenarios (withdrawing from the ICC just to avoid implementing an arrest warrant) so if being an EU member is an issue then it's solvable in the same (extreme) way.

@JBentley I am not talking about extreme scenarios at all.  This type of issue predates ICC warrants.  You think no one balked at hosting a leader from an embarrassingly rightwing "ally" during the Cold War?  Like say Pinochet?  Netanyahu's reputation is not a hill worth dying for most European countries and deploying an "extreme scenario" makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  They can always "make amends" by inviting his successor.

@ItalianPhilosopher We seem to be at cross-wires. The question is about whether a country could avoid enforcing an arrest warrant by withdrawing from the ICC. My comment was a reply to the first sentence of your answer ("They certainly could (EU obligations aside)"). I was merely trying to say that if a country is willing to withdraw from the ICC then it can apply the same logic to the EU obligations. That's all I was saying. Nothing more than that. What I am specifically not saying is that it would make sense to do so.

Not just Hungary, but Austria and Argentina too strongly support Israel on being anti-ICC.

@sfxedit Argentina is not in Europe (and, well, Milei).  And Austria seems to have a hard-right based coalition, which would put it roughly in Italy's case, which I already touched upon.  I wouldn't hold my breath on Bibi doing much visiting  in most of Europe overall.  In fact, visiting only some small European countries might just highlight the inability to visit the others, so may not even be worth engaging in.

@ItalianPhilosopher We'll have to wait and see. See my updated answer - apparently Italy is now campaigning in G7 to "suspend" ICC proceedings "temporarily" against Israeli leaders till the conflict "ends".

Technically speaking, Article 127 of the Rome Statute requires states  withdrawing  from the ICC to wait a  year for the withdrawal to go in effect and is not supposed have any effect on prosecution that has already started.
Realistically  speaking, even if they don't withdraw, member countries  are always free to ignore the ICC with no consequence. Putin visited Mongolia despite the ICC arrest warrant for him, with no consequence to anyone involved. Mongolia even went as far as to  declare ‘unwavering support’ for the ICC despite blatantly  ignoring their arrest warrant and rolling out the red carpet for Putin in an official ceremony.
https://www.ibanet.org/putin-visit-to-mongolia-defies-icc-arrest-warrant-as-world-looks-on
If Mongolia can ignore the ICC despite remaining  a member and ardent supporter there  certainly there wouldn't be any consequence  for a country that has already handed in it's resignation to the ICC not complying with it. It would be like someone handing in his  resignation at work but being contractually required to come in for the next few weeks. What is the boss going to do if the guy says no to something the boss tells him to do?

The embarassment factor for Germany to host Bibi is way different from Mongolia hosting Putin.  See " countries who are strong allies of Israel such as Germany and Austria" above.  Orban can cock a snook at the EU if he wants, he's probably on safer ground with Bibi than with his Putin-cuddling, but most mainstream EU countries are going to want to sit out any visits.
